# Wordpress cracked? Posts not found in dashboard

Tags: errors

I just came back to my site from dinner and was unable to find any posts listed in the dashboard.

After snooping around, I found that my .htaccess file was modified, and some new files were added to my home directory. I deleted the .htaccess code, and the files (they all started with PE).

I see that in the last hour a few posts regarding this have been posted on the wp.org forum site.

Is anyone else having trouble with this? Is there any more code for me to delete?

thanks.

Comment: Can you add a few urls to the wp forums? I couldn't locate any.

Comment: Shared hosting, or private host? It's very possible your permissions were too open on a shared host, ie. 666 on your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress). Do a good job cleaing or you'll be doing it all over again. Who is your host? Check with them, too. Some hosts are better than others when it comes to security and helping with cleaning up after hacks.

Answer (score 0):

did you update to v3.0.2?

if not, my guess is that maybe someone used [**this**](http://wordpress.org/news/2010/11/wordpress-3-0-2/) to gain access to your website and then deleted all your posts...

> *"This maintenance release fixes a moderate security issue that could allow a malicious Author-level user to gain further access to the site, addresses a handful of bugs, and provides some additional security enhancements."*

hope you got backup...